How to zoom in in Apple Notes on iCloud in browser
I use Apple Notes  on my iPad, and I want to make sure that I can access them if my iPad stops working.
On my PC (not Mac) if I access iCloud via Google Chrome my larger notes are zoomed out.
How can I zoom into the notes on iCloud?

Welcome to Ask Different.  Please ask your notes export question as a stand alone one. You can access the original wording here to copy / paste if needed. The solution to one problem will not resolve the other.

Can you please clarify from which device/OS you are trying to access Notes? You only mention a PC but I assume it works there as expected?

Is the browser's zoom in feature not working? Or is not behaving as expected?
